# PCIe pin out (point of view)

Tags: pinout, pcie

I made a board and I would like to connect it to a PC with a PCIe edge connector. The PC will be the root complex (master) and my board the endpoint (slave).

I have a question about the pinout of the edge connector. According to this website: https://pinouts.ru/Slots/pci_express_pinout.shtml the pins A16 and A17 are the receiver lanes et the pins are the transmitter lanes. But from which point of view? From the root complex (PC) or from the daughterboard?

In Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) it's stated that the point of view is from the motherboard and not from the board where the connector is mounted (like UART for example).

That means if you are a making a daughterboard with a PCIe edge connector you need to connect the pin from the motherboard point of view ? In other terms TX from processor daugtherboard to RX of edge PCIe connector (edge connector of the daugtherboard)?

It is true or am I losing my mind ?

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pins named receive are the receive pins on a motherboard by default so they must be card transmit pins by default. If the devices support lane reversal then they can decide which one transmits or receives instead of using default.

Comment: @E.T Please review the site rules: "Thanks and other statements of appreciation are unnecessary, and like other chit chat should not be included." If the answer was helpful or correct, upvote it or accept it as an answer.